# display:none consome dados?

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

Algumas questões sobre o que ocorre quando utilizamos a propriedade `display:none` do css:

**O elemento é carregado e não é apresentado? Ou não chega a ser carregado (e por consequência não consome dados)?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Ele é carregado**. Caso você veja no `Inspector de elemento` você verá que ele está lá, só está escondido com o `display:none`. Um bom exemplo para você ver que ele é carregado e consome dados, é você fazer um loop de linhas com por exemplo, 50 mil registros; você verá que irá demorar um tempo para realizar o processo, mas ao findar, ele não aparecerá nada, pois está com o `display:none`.

Answer (score 3):

> In addition to the many different display box types, the value none
>   lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none, all
>   descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document
>   is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree.

O [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) diz que o documento é renderizado como se o elemento não existisse na árvore DOM. Isto significa que o navegador não irá processar suas informações de visibilidade, mas ele permanecerá na árvore DOM, permitindo o acesso através de javascript, por exemplo. Para efeitos de **apresentação**, o elemento não existe.

> used to describe the presentation of a document
>   written in HTML or XML (including various XML languages like SVG or
>   XHTML). CSS describes how the structured element must be rendered on
>   screen, on paper, in speech, or on other media.

Devemos levar em consideração também que o `display` é uma propriedade CSS e portanto deve **descrever a apresentação** dos elementos na tela.

> The visibility property can be used to hide an element while leaving
>   the space where it would have been. It can also hide rows or columns
>   of a table.

Por fim, diferente do `display: none;` a propriedade `visibility: hidden;` renderiza o elemento na tela mas oculta sua aparência. O elemento continua ocupando seu espaço de acordo com suas definições css. Segue abaixo exemplo de código sobre o comportamento de ambos os atributos.

```css
.box{
  background-color: red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  }

.hidden{
  visibility: hidden; 
  background-color: red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
 }

.none{
  display: none; 
  background-color: red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="hidden"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="none"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depende. **O HTML certamente é carregado.** **Mas se o elemento contiver imagens, iframes** ou outras coisas carregadas separadamente, o navegador terá a chance de não carregá-las enquanto o *display* estiver setado para *none*.

Como um exemplo concreto, numa aplicação que fiz e testei no Chrome do desktop constatei que um iframe dentro de um div com display:none não era carregado até o momento de exibir o div. Era fácil ver isso pela velocidade de carregamento, pelas ferramentas de desenvolvimento do navegador ou também pelos logs do servidor.

Eu não posso garantir que navegadores de dispositivos móveis têm esse mesmo comportamento, por isso seria bom testar a sua página com cuidado em diversas situações, até porque a resposta pode mudar à medida que novas versões de navegadores são lançadas e aperfeiçoadas.

Answer (score -1):

Posso estar errado mas tenho quase certeza que não é carregado. Elementos com display:nome ficam de fora na hora do Render Tree, diferentemente do visibility: hidden que não só carrega o elemento quanto ocupa "espaço" no DOM.